How to find the no. Of Triplets satisfying the following equation.
How to find the no. of triplets {$x,y,z$} satisfying $x^{x}+y^{y}+z^{z}=3$ ?
Generally in competitive examinations like JEE, CUET, ISI, CMI, IYMC, etc. a student is being asked questions regarding finding the no. of triplets {$x,y,z$}.
For e.g. if we are told to find the no. of triplets satisfying $x+y+z=3$, then the answer is very simple. That is there are infinitely many triplets {$x,y,z$} satisfying the condition $x+y+z=3$.
But for my equation that is $x^{x}+y^{y}+z^{z}=3$ we can easily say that {$x,y,z$}={$1,1,1$} is satisfying the given condition. Interestingly we can also say that the triplets {$x,y,z$}={$2,1,0$} is not satisfying the given condition. Why? The answer is very simple. Let's see the reason below:
$x^{x}=2$ , $y^{y}=1$ , $z^{z}=0$.
Now if we clearly observe then we can easily say that Lambert W Function is not working for $z^{z}=0$.
$z^{z}=0$
$\implies z\ln(z)=\ln(0)$
Now we everyone know that $\ln(0)$ is undefined.
Whereas for $x^{x}=2$ the Lambert W Function is easily working.
$x^{x}=2$
$\implies x\ln(x)=\ln(2)$
$\implies te^{t}=\ln(2)$, where $\ln(x)=t$.
$\implies W(te^{t})=W(\ln(2))$
$\implies t=W(\ln(2))$
$\implies x=e^{W(\ln(2)))}$
But still I really don't know how many no. of triplets other than {$x,y,z$}={$1,1,1$} will satisfy the given condition.
Do let me know pls.
Wishes
Suresh

are $x,y,z$ integers?

A first step could be to show that $x,y,z$ lie in the range $[-1,2]$

No it can be any number@TCiur

But if $x,y,z$ is equal to $2,-1$ then $x^{x}+y^{y}+z^{z}$ is not equal to $3$. You can also check

I meant that $-1 \leq x,y,z \leq 2$. But this is only when $x,y,z$ are integers. In general you have infinitely many solutions

Yes, you are correct. I thought it in wrong way. But if I say that how many integer solutions will the triplets {$x,y,z$} have ? Then is the answer $1$ ?

you also have $0^0 = 1$.

1st U need to know the field of number want to find, then try to plug values, take some easy substitution (y=mx & z=kx) then try . this substitutions not works when given equation doesn't have any solution.  These kind of equations are called exponential Diophantine equations.
